# Functional React Component : Composition Examples

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can you please share some good examples for the below pattern. Also what is this pattern called ?

- Building a functional react component which needs to have a JSX component as a children but as a Parent's property

Example,

```
<Parent prop1="ParentName" props2="anotherParentProp">
     <Child childprop1="child comp 1" childprop2={true} />
     <Child childprop1="child comp 2" childprop2={false} />
</Parent>
```

In the Parent Functional component I need to use\read the child node (children) as properties so that Parent's component will render accordingly.

Parent functional component

```
import ...
export interface IParentProps{
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  children: ???
}

export const Parent = (props: IParentProps) => {
...

//here I need all the children (JSX) as properties to be read and do the needful

}
```

Comment: Hi, I would recommend editing your question to make it more focused. Right now your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct). This question may also be a matter of more opinion than can be answered objectively.